# Why does my rake file code run every time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

I would like for some code to run whenever an input file is changed.  Here is what I wrote in `seed.rake`:

```
INPUT_FILE = 'input-file'
INPUT_FILE_PROCESSED = '.input-file-processed'

file INPUT_FILE_PROCESSED => [INPUT_FILE, :environment].flatten do
    # Expensive code omitted.
    touch INPUT_FILE_PROCESSED
end

task all: [INPUT_FILE_PROCESSED]
```

I thought this would run the expensive code only when `INPUT_FILE` was newer than `INPUT_FILE_PROCESSED`, but every time I run `rake seed:all`, the expensive code runs:

```
$ rake seed:all
[2 minutes pass]
$ ls -al  .input-file-processed input-file
Jul 18 14:56 .input-file-processed
Jul 18 14:12 input-file
$ rake seed:all
[2 minutes pass]
$ ls -al  .input-file-processed input-file
Jul 18 15:01 .input-file-processed
Jul 18 14:12 input-file
```

I am using rake 10.3.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dependency on the :environment task screws up the file modification time dependency checking (I imagine this is because the :environment task is always run).

You can depend on just the file and then require the environment manually:

```
file INPUT_FILE_PROCESSED => INPUT_FILE do
  require_relative '../../config/environment'
```